# Wordpress Child Theme Not Appearing In Dashboard

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bitnami

From what I understand, I go to my website dashboard > appearance > themes, and there I am supposed to select the child theme that I create. But it doesn't appear there.

Here is the dir structure of my themes folder:

```
---- wp-content
   ----- themes
      ----- PlatformPro_v1.3.0
           ----- style.css
       ----- PlatformProChildTheme
            ----- style.css
```

This is exactly what I have in my PlatformProChildTheme style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name:     PChild
Description:    PChild
Author:         John Smith
Template:       PlatformPro_v1.3.0
*/

@import url("../PlatformPro_v1.3.0/style.css");
```

Answer (score 5):

`Template:` parameter is wrong:

> **Template**. (required) directory name of parent theme, case-sensitive.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

It should read `Template: PlatformPro_v1.3.0`

Comment: As of right now, this is my style.css:    /*
    Theme Name:     PChild
    Description:    PChild
    Author:         John Smith
    Template:       PlatformPro_v1.3.0
    */

    @import url("../PlatformPro_v1.3.0/style.css");

Answer (score 0):

A child theme is part of your activated theme. So if you activate Platformpro, and you have the child theme folder in the parent theme folder, it will be activated once you activists the parent theme.

As long as your path name is correct, what you have showed above is exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: I have Platformpro activated at the moment. The PlatformProChildTheme is inside of the /wp-content/themes folder.